# How to place an image over a _full_ (including bleed) page in memoir? 

Tags: graphics, margins, memoir

I need to include a jpg into my document created with memoir as a full separate page. The jpg is colored and has 3 mm bleed out into the stock paper. A bit naively I thought I could just use negative `vspace` and `hspace` but it is not working very intuitively. This is my attempt for the moment:

```
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir}

\stockaiv
\settrims{20mm}{20mm}
\trimFrame

\pagesmallroyalvo

\setbinding{4mm}
\settypeblocksize{*}{24.5pc}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setulmarginsandblock{6pc}{7pc}{*}
\setmarginnotes{6pt}{6pc}{12pt}
\strictpagecheck
\setlength{\topskip}{1.6\topskip}
\checkandfixthelayout
\sloppybottom

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\vspace*{-\uppermargin}
\vspace*{-6mm} % no idea where this space is comming from
\vspace*{-3mm}
\hspace*{-\spinemargin}
\hspace*{-5mm} % no idea where this space is comming from
\hspace*{-3mm}
% input a page sized jpg with 3 mm bleed
\includegraphics{page.jpg}

\end{document}
```

> EDIT: I have hacked up something looking like what I have written
>   above. There are some *magic* numbers there though. I would love to
>   udnerstand where they are comming from...

Comment: I realised that `\trimtop` is the diff between the stock paper so I don't want that there. I also realised that I can't have a white line before the `\includegraphics` so changd those two things. However there is still som air left between the paper border and my figure and I don't know where it comes from...
Oh nd thre was a missing - before the 3mm but that was just a typo... :)

Comment: I would just convert the JPG into a PDF and use the `pdfpages` package: `\includepdf{image}`. Maybe it even works with JPGs directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Option 1**: Using the [`eso-pic` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).

The `eso-pic` package provides a means to add content to the background|foreground of a|every page using a number of commands:

- `\AddToShipoutPictureBG`: Content added to **background** of **every** page;
- `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*`: Content added to **background** of **current** page;
- `\AddToShipoutPictureFG`: Conent added to **foreground** of **every** page;
- `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*`: Content added to **foreground** of **current** page.

The default coordinate origin for content placement is the lower-left corner of the page (also obtained through the package option `pscoord`), but this can be modified to the upper-left corner of the page if needed (by using the package option `texcoord`).

Additional macros for placing content at predefined locations is provided by (with their meaning being obivous)

- `\AtPageUpperLeft`
- `\AtPageLowerLeft`
- `\AtPageCenter`
- `\AtTextUpperLeft`
- `\AtTextLowerLeft`
- `\AtTextCenter`
- `\AtStockUpperLeft`
- `\AtStockLowerLeft`
- `\AtStockCenter`

The definitions of `\..Stock...`, `\..Page...` and `\..Text` coincide with `memoir`'s use of the lengths `\stock...`, `\paper...` and `\text...`. Consequently, using your document preamble settings, the following minimal example

```
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Dummy text/Lorem Ipsum
\usepackage{eso-pic}% www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1-5]% Dummy text/Lorem Ipsum

\clearpage \null
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to current page
  \AtStockLowerLeft{% Add picture to lower-left corner of paper stock
    \includegraphics[width=\stockwidth,height=\stockheight]{tiger}}% http://latex.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/images/tiger.eps
}
\clearpage

\lipsum[6-10]% Dummy text/Lorem Ipsum

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Image on single page using eso-pic]

I would assume the lengths used here are much more self-explanatory, and can be modified (if needed) to produce exactly what you want.

---

**Option 2**: Using the [`pdfpages` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).

The `pdfpages` package allows for the inclusion of external documents using the `\includepdf[...]{...}` command. It can even include images in the formats supported by pdfTeX (PNG, JPG, etc.), although this has to be explicitly specified in the form `<image.ext>`. Using a similar setup as above, you would use

```
\includepdf[noautoscale]{<image.ext>}
```

to insert `<image.ext>` without scaling into your document. Assuming that your image is sized exactly as needed, this should also produce the desired result. See the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) for more options (like `fitpaper=true` if you want the paper to sized accord to your image; this would allow you to use your printer's "Fit to page" printing option).

Comment: I am trying option 1 but since I have bleed on my pictures I need to use `\AtPageLowerLeft` and somehow remove some space. I can get `\hspace*{-6mm}` to work but for some reason I can't get `\vspace*{6mm}` to do anything. Is there a reason for why vertical space doesn't work inside the block you suggest?

Comment: @jonalv: For horizontal alignment, `\hspace[*]{>len>}` should work fine. For vertical alignment, use `\raisebox{<len>}{<stuff>}` from the `graphicx` package. In your case, `\raisebox{-6mm}{<image>}` should work.