# Include a single PDF image that is on an otherwise empty page

Tags: graphics, pdf, crop

I am using [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) to generate a vector based diagram. Then, I export it to PDF, because I want to keep the vector format and want to build my complete document to PDF later on.

When I include my diagram it uses a complete page to include that diagram. How do I import a diagram (PDF) into my document? It only has a single image and I want it to only include that image.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
% more bla...

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/diagram.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

I was already thinking of generating `ps2pdf`, but that would still give me a PDF file with the same problems probably.

Comment: It sounds like one of your issues is you want to crop the PDF to remove the whitespace around it. That is answered in several places on the site, such as [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents). pdfcop and Briss are 2 good choices.

Comment: Note that you don't need a `figure` environment to use `\includegraphics`. You only need one if you want the image to float (which you apparently don't if you use `[H]`) and/or if you want a `\caption` (which can be included using other means as well).

Comment: Either tell Dia to generate a cropped PDF without any whitespace (i.e. not a full A4 or letter sized PDF) or use `pdfcrop` to generate such a PDF from it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I haven't found any options in Dia to do that. I found *page setup*, but it can only create fixed size papers. So that's a shame.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Where can I find to include graphics without float? I have read the `caption` documentation, but it doesn't seem to tell me how to do that. And: Why not use float with `H`? It works fine...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a couple of options with this "problem".

1. You can use an external approach and trim the whitespace around the image. [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) is capable of doing this and uses the following interface

   ```
   pdfcrop [options] <input[.pdf]> [output file]
   ```

   where `[ ]` denotes optional specifications. If your Dia-exported PDF image, (say) `image.pdf`, consists of entire blank page with *only* an image (nothing else on the page like a page number or header/footer), then you can type

   ```
   pdfcrop image.pdf image.pdf
   ```

   which will trim the excess whitespace, leaving only the image in the PDF. Then you can include it as usual without having to specify the `width` parameter to `\includegraphics`:

   ```
   \includegraphics{image}
   ```
2. Another (somewhat) external approach would be to use `\includegraphics` is the only component in a [`standalone` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) using the following format:

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
   \begin{document}
   \includegraphics{<options>}{<image>}
   \end{document}
   ```

   or

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
   \usepackage[active,graphics,tightpage]{preview}% http://ctan.org/pkg/preview
   \begin{document}
   \includegraphics[width=4cm]{tiger}
   \end{document}
   ```

   This should produce a trimmed version of your image that you can incorporate in your document in the usual way. `standalone` uses the [`preview` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/preview) to aid in this functionality, so you could use `preview` as well, as in the second example.

   As commented by @MartinScharrer, this might not work as expected if your bounding box is already a full (whitespace included) page.
3. You can perform the trimming option from within LaTeX using the `trim` option of `\includegraphics`. From the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf):

   > **`bb`** The argument should be four dimensions, separated by spaces. These denote
   >   the 'Bounding Box' of the printed region within the ﬁle.
   >
   > **`viewport`** The `viewport` key takes four arguments, just like `bb`. However in this case the values are taken relative to the origin speciﬁed by the bounding box in the ﬁle. So to 'view' the `1in` square in the bottom left hand corner of the area speciﬁed by the bounding box, use the argument `viewport=0 0 72 72`.
   >
   > **`trim`** Similar to `viewport`, but here the four lengths specify the amount to remove or add to each side. `trim= 1 2 3 4` 'crops' the picture by `1bp` at the left, `2bp` at the bottom, `3bp` on the right and `4bp` at the top.

   However, you'd have to know (or by trial-and-error) what the bounding box of the contained image is in `bp` measurements.
4. Use the [`adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) which provides `\clipbox`. It works in a similar manner to the `trim` option of `\includegraphics`. It also provides an `export` package option which exports functionality to `\includegraphics`. Read the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf) for more information on this.

---

**Edit**:

- If you export your image from Dia as an EPS and it is already tightly cropped, then [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) can convert them to PDF and you're good-to-go. If the bounding box is not tight, you could try using [`epstool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstool) to tighten it.

Comment: Note that for 2. that `standalone` (actually the used `preview` package) doesn't crop white spaces from included images. It simply crops to the TeX bounding box of the image, which makes it useless in this case. Also `\pagestyle{empty}` is already included for this class (and not even required as long `preview` is enabled).

Comment: Option 1 sounds like a great idea. I will try to install this and see if it runs. Strange that there is no such way for creating cropped PDF's from out Dia. Could I also create an EPS and do something with that instead or is that harder?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the **standalone** document class instead of, say, the article document class? It'll automatically crop off all whitespace.

Comment: He is talking about an external PDF which didn't got created by LaTeX, so `standalone` is no option here.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can use the tool called [eps2pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/eps2pdf). I can let Dia print an EPS file and then let eps2pdf change it to a pdf that has no a4 format. Since this is not the actual question I asked, I will accept the other answer, but this is how I finally did it.

1. Dia: Export to an eps file
2. eps2pdf: Export the file to pdf
3. `\includegraphics{mypdf}`