# How to export a pdf from a word file which is not one page long but smaller according to the drawing size?

Tags: pdf, pdftex, crop, word-to-latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I crop included PDF documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents)

I have a drawing from a word file. I export it in a pdf format and i import to my tex file as a figure for a paper. The problem is that the pdf file has the size of a A4 paper while the drawing is only the 1/4 of the A4 and it is placed at the top of the pdf. As such there is a big blank area in my paper. How can i export this from Word in a smaller pdf file?

Comment: 1. You can take a screen shot and use paint afterwards, 2. select only the figure, paste it in paint or inkscape and export it pdf, 3 use `clip` function of `graphicx` package with `viewport` option. Will these be useful?

Comment: the use of a tool `pdfcrop` is described in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/).  there are some drawbacks -- if there is a page number on the pdf file, that will be included in the cropped area.

Comment: Do any of the answers in the question that barbara linked to help you?  If so, we'll probably close this as a duplicate of that better to help others.  If not, it would be useful to know why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once done this in this way:

1. export to pdf from word. The pdf has the size of a page.
2. open the pdf with Inkscape, and export to eps. The eps file would have the right size.
3. use the eps file in latex.

The eps file can be convert to pdf with the right size, or you may export the file directly to pdf from Inkscape. Remember to check "export area is drawing" when save as eps or pdf from Inkscape.

There seems to be some bug in direct copy paste from word to Inkscape, but I cannot recall. If it works, it'll be better.

Comment: i import the pdf to inkspace but when saved in pdf again the size is the same. Is there any way of resizing in inkscape.

Comment: @curious Can't you use eps file? the eps files have the right size.

Comment: @curious Check "export area is drawing" when save as pdf.

Comment: you can't easilly use eps files with pdflatex

Comment: There is no reason to go over (E)PS, you can read and write PDFs with Inkscape directly. Try using the "export area drawing" option when exporting the PDF. This can even be done using the command line: `inkscape --export-area-drawing --export-pdf output.pdf input.pdf`. However, this changed the fonts in my test file. I would consider using `pdfcrop` instead.

Comment: Ok it worked, the problem now is that it is very very very big inside my latex! how can i make it smaller? Inside latex or from inkscape is better?

Comment: @curious I would do it in latex, explicitly specifying the size of image when including it, use `\includegraphics[width=...]{...}`

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:** You can use the same long pdf file and clip it with the following technique.

Let us say that we have this picture:

[image]

We set out to clip this picture. Here is the full code. Hope the code explains it all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fullpage}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{chick}
\caption{A chick in full}
\end{figure}

\section{\texttt{trim}}
\texttt{trim=l b r t} $\rightarrow$ This option will crop the imported image by l from the left, b from the bottom, r from the right, and t from the top. Where l, b, r and t are lengths.

\texttt{clip} $\rightarrow$     For the \texttt{trim} option to work, you must set \verb|clip=true|.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[trim = 5mm 25mm 5mm 2mm, clip, width=3cm]{chick}
\caption{A chick not in full using \texttt{trim}}
\end{figure}

\section{\texttt{viewport}}
\texttt{viewport=lx ly ux uy} $\rightarrow$ This option will crop the imported image by a box (rectangular/square) determined by the points with co-ordinates (lx,ly) (measured from south west point) and (ux,uy) (measured from north east point). Here I used `l' for lower and `u` for upper.

\texttt{clip} $\rightarrow$     For the \texttt{viewport} option to work, you must set \verb|clip=true|.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[viewport = 5mm 25mm 40mm 55mm, clip, width=3cm]{chick}
\caption{A chick not in full using \texttt{viewport}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I have used `fullpage` package so as to bring every thing in one page (personal preference).

Comment: Note that you can get the real bounding box of an PDF image using Ghostscript, e.g.: `gs -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -f input.pdf` will print it in integer and high resolution using PS points (`bp` in TeX). Use them with `viewport`. This is done by `pdfcrop` which might actually be easier and will just increase the file size of the PDF by a few kb.