# Insert a piece of PDF file as image

Tags: graphics, pdf

Recently I learned how to include just one page of a PDF file as image using `\includegraphics`, but now I need to include just part of the page and *not*  the entire page.

How can I include just 50% or 65% of a PDF page as image in a document?

Comment: For most uses I've found it easiest to trim the pdf with an external GUI program. To trim in TeX you'll need to now the precise offsets. Or do you need to automatise the work-flow?

Comment: @Florian Hi, i didnt find any program to do that, most of them just cut off pages and didn't give me the option to cut a part of page, could you recomend me one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trim and clip an included image using the `trim` and `clip` key-values:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a} \par
\includegraphics[trim=100 50 100 50,clip]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

The elements supplied to `trim=<lx> <ly> <ux> <uy>` are the bounding box values in `bp`s.
Read up on the details in the [Graphics Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) (section **4 The Graphics packages**, p 7 onward).

[`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) provides similar functionality.

Comment: Just to help the others:
[trim = <left> <down> <right> <up>, clip]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question [How can I crop included PDF documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents): Use `pdfcrop` from Heiko Oberdiek (requires [Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads)).

Comment: Thanks, but actually i'm not using a linux system. : /
But i'll keep i t as reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows, you could just use the 'snipping tool' in programfiles/accessories to create an image of the portion of the pdf you want to put in as a picture.

Comment: It is not an option, because there are lost of a lot of quality in the image. Too much details.