# How to use only half an image?

Tags: graphics, crop

Is it possible to include only half an image? I'm looking to include only the right half of an image and discard the left half.

If there is a simple way to accomplish that, it would make more sense in my case than to generate new images.

Comment: Here are a couple of questions/answers that might be useful: [crop an inserted image](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image) and [crop included pdf documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the `crop` and `trim` options for `\includegraphics` command.

Example:

```
\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 80mm 20mm 5mm, clip, width=3cm]{image}
```

The options for `trim` is: `trim=left bottom right top`, where it cropped by the appropriate amount from the sides.

So, including only the right half would look like:

```
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\settowidth{\imagewidth}{\includegraphics{image}}
\includegraphics[trim=0.5\imagewidth{} 0 0 0, clip, width = 0.1\imagewidth{}]{image}
```

[Check the code](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/51b604744c2bd7043019012d).

Comment: Thanks. I know of `trim`, but how can I find the image width? Also, why do you need `clip`?

Comment: @TimN: `trim` didn't work without `clip`.

Comment: @TimN `trim` only reduces the size of the resulting box (you’d have overlapping on the left side), `clip` also clips the stuff outside of the box.