# Actually crop vectors in included pdf image with includegraphics trim/crop?

Tags: crop, clip

I've seen [How can I crop included PDF documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents) - but it doesn't quite address my problem.

Let me illustrate with MWE - this is `test1.tex`, which you can compile with `pdflatex test1.tex`, which generates the "image" `test1.pdf`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\title{A special source document for testing}
\author{Ego Myself}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

And here is `test2.tex`, which you can compile with `pdflatex test2.tex`, which is the "main" document, that includes `test1.pdf` as an image:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\title{A normal document}
\author{Else Someone}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[11]

% [trim=left bottom right top]
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,page=1,trim=1.20in 6in 2.5in 1.1in,clip]{test1.pdf}}
  \caption{Excerpt from special source document}
  \label{figure:spec-source}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The PDF result of `test2.pdf` looks like this in `evince`, Ubuntu 14.04:

[image: test2_1.png]

All looks good, actually - until I decide to drag around with the mouse in the document to select stuff - then I can see:

[image: test2_2.png]

Ouch - actually ALL of the original vectors in the PDF that is included as image, are also present (meaning, eating away file size/disk space for nothing) in the main document - even if they are made invisible by the `trim/clip`!

Any way to actually remove these vectors that are made invisible by `trim/clip` (so they are not present as data at all in the "main" document, and thus would not be "selectable" even if invisible)?

Comment: The is normal PDF behavior, not specific to TEX. The "cropped" material is still there, just not visible. Ever form a frame with your hands, to visualize how an outdoor scene would look in a picture? That doesn't make anything dematerialize, it just blocks the view. Same with PDF. There may (repeat, may) be some techniques for removing at least some of the blocked material, but I only know how to do that with professional software.

Comment: Thanks for that, @RobtAll - feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Just a comment, not an answer. Some of the TeXperts might know of a way to minimize the effect, so let them have their say.

Comment: Afterthought: This is a serious issue in "the real world." Some law firm or political office creates a PDF, in which sensitive material is "omitted." But it's still there in the PDF, and you don't need a secret decoder to see it. Oops. So, there is professional software (maybe even free stuff) that will locate and remove material not intended to be seen. But I don't know how good it is, in terms of removing partial material; I believe that any individual vector object (including a text letter) is all-or-nothing.