# Hiding page numbers in pdfs inserted using includepdf command

Tags: pdfpages, crop

This may not be possible but let me ask anyway (the magic of Latex is well known)

I am inserting some pdfs using `\includepdf` command. Some of these pdfs have page numbers appearing in them at the bottom. I know the files in which they appear and the location of the page numbers is consistent (middle bottom). Is it possible to hide or remove the page numbers somehow?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents