trim and clip \includegraphics PDF leaves selectable text artefact
I regularly use \includegraphics with trim + clip option to e.g. include a single panel from a larger figure in a .pdf file.
I recently noticed in the Evince PDF editor I can select text objects from the included figure that were cropped out (and so otherwise invisible). In other words, the full .pdf is included in a hidden layer. This does not seem ideal as makes highlighting text confusing, and presumably may cause issue with OCR/accessibility.
Is there a way to ensure the cropped content really is discarded, short of cutting up the original .pdf (which can be messy)?
For a minimal example, compile this standalone tikzpicture with a line of X characters:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Calling the output line.pdf,
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
A sentence of text in the first column of the document.
\newpage
\includegraphics[trim={5cm 0 0 0}]{line.pdf}
\end{document}

(twocolumn is just to make the overlap clear)
Here is the output in Evince with nothing selected:

And when I click-select text in the left column:

As you can see, highlighting reveals the cropped context of line.pdf.
Note whether you can view the hidden layer does appear to depend on your editor. I couldn't select the hidden X in Okular, for example.
Edit: The question (or rather, its answer) Included PDF image has invisible, but selectable text provides much useful information, but is different because: i. My input .pdf has no hidden content (which we now know means its CropBox has not been changed), i.e., if includegraphics were used without trim, clip there would be no hidden text or artefacts, and ii., I am specifically questioning how trim and clip introduce this (presumably by adjusting the Cropbox); if this is expected and further if there it a TeX-way to avoid it.
Note that because of i. the accepted answer to that question cannot apply. Voting to reopen as I would like to provide an answer to my question that may be useful to others.

If you want the content to be actually gone, you could edit the pdf e.g. with inkscape and delete everything you don't want to show.

no you can't discard that. You have a vector graphic with curves, so clipping isn't simply done by removing some pixels.

Inkscape was the first thing I tried, but unfortunately that involves an import which can result in characters lost or substituted for fonts not your system (and other approximations).
I'm currently looking into using pdfcrop with comes with most TeX distributions

Inkspace has a 'Resize to content' feature @UlrikeFischer which does actually remove unwanted portions of the document.

I didn't say it is impossible, but it needs a full blown graphic application and so can't be done when you import a graphic with the primitive engine commands.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Selecting the nodes you want and copying to a new document is a practical way to go about that. But yes, it's not convenient.
Some possible solutions here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents
Using pdfcrop didn't appear to work.

Similar results using Ghostscript and GUI tools like pdfCropMargins and krop. The crux is removing unwanted parts of a PDF file is not trivial. Inkscape editing works, but can lead to missing glyphs on import. I expect there's another graphics application as @UlrikeFischer says that might be more effective.

Unfortunately not, the GhostScript command in the accepted answer has no effect. Has given me some leads to look into though, thanks.

With respect okular, the hidden  text also can be copied some times. If you copy the two columns, for instance.

The cropped text remains selectable because trim+clip of includegraphics does not remove any content from the including .pdf, only hides those parts not in the calculated viewport.
A similar issue (Included PDF image has invisible, but selectable text) occurs when an included file has been 'cropped' (i.e. regions hidden) by an external program. Specifically, the CropBox of the .pdf (checked with pdfinfo -box file.pdf) was reduced from the MediaBox. As includegraphics uses CropBox - where available - to determine what is shown, in this case even without using trim+clip invisible content will be inserted into your document.
The crux is that actually discarding parts of the .pdf is a non-trivial operation. Most tools (briss, krop, pdfcropmargins...) simply change CropBox, which is the property most viewers (and includegraphics) use to determine what should be shown. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to actually remove .pdf cropped content in LaTeX, using graphicx or any other package (I have tried combinations of tikz and standalone documents with negative margins).
The only real* recourse then is to an .svg editor such as inkscape. If you open the .pdf to be included in inkscape, it is quite easy to change the canvas size using the Resize to content operation (under Document Properties):

[Alternatively, one may use Export to save a particular region to a .pdf]
*If you do not care about having scalable graphics, you could always use ImageMagick to crop the file, which will rasterise it in the process.
As an aside, this presents quite a fun way to send secret messages to colleagues - just be sure your boss doesn't have an OCR Reader or is liable to hand things to an AI chatbot! (Below is the result of passing a file with text hidden in this way to ChatPDF)

