# How to adjust memoir crop marks line length

Tags: memoir, crop

I've been searching for the similiar question but still have no luck. I'm following [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124825/image-behind-and-beyond-crop-marks) to create crop marks in `memoir` class and would like to adjust the length of the crop mark lines. Here's my MWE.

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}
\setstocksize{216mm}{146mm}
\settrimmedsize{210mm}{140mm}{*}
\settrims{3mm}{3mm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{20mm}{15mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{20mm}{*}
% \trimLmarks
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to adjust the length of crop marks line (`\trimXmarks`)?
2. <strike>If I use `\trimLmarks`, it creates good crop marks but just too short in my opinion. How to increase the line length?</strike>

Thanks.

Update:

I just added the following code under the `\checkandfixthelayout` line.

```
\renewcommand*{\trimmark}{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \unitlength 5mm % set new length
    \thinlines
    \put(-2,0){\line(1,0){4}}
    \put(0,-2){\line(0,1){4}}
  \end{picture}}
```

... <strike>and it answers question no. 1. As with no. 2 (using `\trimLmarks`), I don't know yet.</strike>

...and it works.