# Best way to define a Latex document with crop mark for printing

Tags: memoir, article, crop, cropmarks

I'd like to do a document that will be printed by a professional printer. To print it I need to add a margin around the document so that during the page cutting no blank margin will appear. Here is what I want:

- Be able to display the crop marks above the text, pictures, and tikz (using absolute positionning in the page)
- Be able to output easily only the document without the margin around the document, without changing anything.

I tried several things, use memoir, beamer, the crop package... But no one allow me to do that easily. Here is an example using the crop package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in,margin=0.25in,bottom=1in,top=1in,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}
\begin{document}
Hello
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node (back names) [shape=rectangle, fill=blue, minimum height=40mm, minimum width=\paperwidth + 1cm, anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the text goes above the crop mark

[image]

Any idea ? Thank you !

-- EDIT --
I found a kind of solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124825/image-behind-and-beyond-crop-marks/127864#127864), which uses atbegshi that I adapted to work with the crop package:

```
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}\AtBeginShipoutInit
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in,margin=0.25in,bottom=1in,top=1in,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,pdftex]{crop}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
Hello
\null\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (back names) [shape=rectangle, fill=blue, minimum height=40mm, minimum width=\paperwidth + 1cm, anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to embeed all the images that are supposed to be below the crop mark in the code

```
\null\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
% Write here the image
}
```

There are however two problems:

- I don't know how to put the picture above the text AND below the crop marks
- It's a bit heavy to write
- EDIT : and I also realize that it was not possible to use `AddToShipoutPictureBG*` twice...

Comment: Did you run the sample document through pdflatex twice? That is needed for correct positioning of 'remember picture' thingies.

Comment: As you are already using the `geometry` package adding the option `showcrop` to it seems like the best option. However, it also prints the crop marks under your picture, which is a little surprising as it claims to use the `atbegshi` package for printing the crop marks...

Comment: On another note - I would advise against swapping out document classes just for fiddling with crop marks. Use the most appropriate document class for your content (book, maybe?) and find a way to use crop marks with that.

Comment: Although it is not exactly what you have asked for, the `novel` document class has most of it built-in. Not for use with math. But may I ask, are you really sure you need crop marks? The print services I have used do NOT want crop marks, even when the trim size is smaller than the PDF page size. That's because (in `novel` class with PDF/X) there is an invisible "TrimBox" that instructs a fully computerized printing machine where to cut. Only when the paper is manually cut by humans, do they want crop marks.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: yes, running pdflatex several times does not change the result.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer : yes, I don't want to switch document class, I just want to choose the good one. I want to produce at the end a photo book, so I don't mind if it's the class book, beamer, or whatever.

Comment: @RobtAll: Well, I want crop marks so that I can see if I put the pictures deep enough in the margin to be sure I won't get white margin. At the end, the crop marks will be removed, it's just to help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a bit of a kludge. It involves the creation of 3 separate files:

1. the main file with the actual content,
2. a separate file that contains nothing but crop marks, and
3. a wrapper file that uses the `pdfpages` package to overlay the crop marks on top of the content pages. For example:

File `content.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={5in,7in},margin=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor,lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,2, ..., 5}{\lipsum[\x]  \newpage}

\newgeometry{margin=0in}
\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{/data/graphics/fun/popeye-blue}

\end{document}
```

File `emptycrop.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={4in,6in},margin=0.25in,bottom=1in,top=1in,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,pdftex]{crop}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,2, ..., 10}{\null \newpage}

\end{document}
```

File `wrapper.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\includepdf[
   pages=-,
   noautoscale,
   scale=1,
   picturecommand={\put(0,0){\includegraphics[page=\thepage]{emptycrop}}}]
  {content.pdf}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Note that I defined the paper size for the content a bit larger than for the crop mark file. When you compile them all in sequence, the last page of `wrapper.pdf` looks like this:

[image]

While the three-file setup may be a bit clunky, you don't really have to worry about it most of the time - you only have to do this once at the very end.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, the crop marks are still below the pictures...

Comment: @tobiasBora - new answer.

Comment: It seems to work indeed, even if it's a bit complicated ^^ Thank you ! Just a remark: I heard that the trim information is most of the time embedded in the file (I don't know what for).  With this solution I guess that these information is lost, but I don't use it now so I think it should be enough for me... Thanks !

Comment: Hum, another problem of this solution is that when you choose (current page.north), you will refer in fact to the stock page...

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Stock page as opposed to what? Can you post some sample code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Stockpage opposed to paper page (stock page includes the margin). Indeed, I want to put the element in the page by saying "current page.north east" for example, and here, if I write that the element will be in the margin that will be croped. But I found a solution : I also open the crop package in the content.tex file, and I disable the frame.